# Short syntax equivalent

Tags: xml, syntax

What's the difference between

```
        <Crop CropVisible="No"></Crop>
```

and

```
        <Crop CropVisible="No"/>
```

Are both valid?

What is the technical name for this construct?

Notepad++ changes the top one into the bottom one when I reformat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. They are both valid. It is an [empty element tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags) (colloquially known as a self-closing tag) as opposed to a start tag and an end tag.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no difference in XML. It's usually called a self-closing tag (though [Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066451/157247) shows that the spec uses a different term). In both cases, `Crop` is an element with no child elements.

(The answer would be different for HTML, which looks a bit like XML but is quite different.)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-starttags defines "Tags for Empty Elements" as:

> [44]      EmptyElemTag       ::=      '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '/>' [WFC: Unique Att Spec]
>
> Empty-element tags may be used for any element which has no content, whether or not it is declared using the keyword EMPTY.
> For interoperability, the empty-element tag should be used, and should only be used, for elements which are declared EMPTY.
>
> Examples of empty elements:
>
> ```
> <IMG align="left" src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/WWW/w3c_home" />
> <br></br>
> <br/>
> ```

Of course, "SHOULD" means that there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a particular item, but the full implications must be understood and carefully weighed before choosing a different course.

This is the only reference in "Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition)" and "Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.1 (Second Edition)" from W3C.